# How do I include --no-pager in a Git alias?

Tags: git, terminal, alias, git-config

I created a Git alias based off of the [Git Immersion](http://gitimmersion.com/index.html) tutorial by EdgeCase that looks like this:

```
hist = log --pretty=format:\"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]\" --graph --date=short
```

But now it seems to be paging the results — Terminal shows `(END)` after the results are displayed, forcing me to hit <kbd>Q</kbd> to continue working. I read that by adding in the `--no-pager` tag, you can disable this feature; how do I incorporate it into the alias? I've tried it at the end, before the `log`, and right after, and none of them have worked. Git throws an error saying it is an unrecognized argument, or that it changes environment variables. Any advice?

Comment: You really don't want to do this, though. Once you get to using a git project with a sizable history, the log will be *very* long.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do that easily by just turning it into a shell command:

```
hist = "!git --no-pager log ..."
```

Comment: Sorry about the title, my bad. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 10):

Note: with Git 2.18 (Q2 2018), the alias can use a shorter option for `--no-pager`:
"`git --no-pager cmd`" did not have short-and-sweet single letter option. Now it does.

The alias can now be:

```
hist = "!git -P log ..."
```

See [commit 7213c28](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7213c288187bd9ef1e32e4f86c20c55436f1ae90) (03 May 2018) by [Johannes Sixt (`j6t`)](https://github.com/j6t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c9aac55](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9aac55c4e99302e1e365e480eb52c3da2d7c853), 23 May 2018)</sup>

> `git`: add `-P` as a short option for `--no-pager`
>
> It is possible to configure '`less`', the pager, to use an alternate
>   screen to show the content, for example, by setting `LESS=RS` in the
>   environment.
>   When it is closed in this configuration, it switches back to the original screen, and all content is gone.
>
> It is not uncommon to request that the output remains visible in
>   the terminal. For this, the option `--no-pager` can be used.
>   But it is a bit cumbersome to type, even when command completion is
>   available.
>   Provide a short option, `-P`, to make the option more
>   easily accessible.

Comment: in scripts I would prefer writing it out to make it easier to comprehend. When using it on the CLI this is of course still useful.

Comment: @Xerus I agree: no for script, yes for CLI.

Answer (score 4):

The --no-pager option gives an `unrecognized option` error when used after `log`, but it worked by putting --no-pager before log - "git --no-pager log .... " worked

Comment: partial solution is nice - with this approach git does not use a pager for the given command. However, it terminates prematurely with two other messages... #1 - error: warning: exhaustive rename detection was skipped due to too many files.
#2 - warning: you may want to set your diff.renameLimit variable to at least 3072 and retry the command.