# git branch ~(END) on terminal?

Tags: git, command-line, terminal

To note, I'm on Oh-My-Zsh and git 2.17. Whenever I type in git branch, instead of showing me the branches of my git, it shows something like this:

```
~
~
~
~
~
(END)
```

I can quit this by pressing 'q' on my keyboard, but I'm still confused as to why this is appearing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git-branch command behaves like less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48341920/git-branch-command-behaves-like-less)

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Git pipes long output into what's called a pager by default, which can make it easier to view the output if it doesn't fit on a screen. The ~ characters indicate that those lines were not in the original output, but it's showing them so that you can scroll down past the bottom (i.e. the last line of output can go up to the top of the screen).

You typically can use the arrow keys to scroll up or down, and can exit by pressing q.

Comment: Right, I understand that part of git. But what I'm concerned about is that running git init then git branch doesn't show me anything.

Comment: It's because you have not committed anything. git branch displays all branches. Since a branch points to a commit and you have not performed commit , it displays nothing

Comment: Thank you! Just a question, is there a reason that it doesn't show the master branch?

Comment: Any branch in git points to the last commit. Even the master branch needs a commit to be displayed. So , it does not even show the master branch.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you so much!

Comment: @BrianPark If you've ever used Vim, there also this kind of thing is shown to indicate lines.

Comment: `can exit by pressing q` helps

Answer (score 59):

You can replace the pager with `less` so it doesn't "scroll" outputs less than the height of the terminal.

`git config --global --replace-all core.pager "less -F -X"`

I found it from this q. Took a while to find compared to OPs questions, so I figured I'd drop it here in case anyone else has the same issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14118014/4881742

Comment: In macOS git this is extremely necessary, otherwise it gets stuck in ~end

Worked perfectly!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 22):

Note that:

- `git -P branch` would display an empty list, without pager ([Git 2.18 for the `-P`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50537464/6309))
- [`git branch | less -F`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42563543/6309) would do the same
- [`export LESS=-JMQRiFX`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31/7490) followed by any Git command would avoid the pager (for any result less than a screen)

Answer (score 13):

you can use this " git config --global core.pager cat " to change your git configuration to set that as default the problem is sometime when you use or install Oh My Zsh the configuration is change

Comment: Perfect. Oh My Zsh was probably why. It's been one of those things I've just dealt with. Then one day it's, "You know what, I'm fixing this". lol Thanks.

Comment: worked perfectly, like charm